# Какие misfire инструкции нужно установить для ImmediateTrigger?

Tags: java, quartz

Я хочу, чтобы в моём приложении одновременно выполнялось не более пяти заданий, остальные становились в очередь и запускались только после того, как какие-либо из работающих пяти потоков освободятся. Вот мой код:

```
SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties");
sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
sched.start();
String jobName = generateJobDetailName();
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(jobName, GRP_Immediate, MyJob.class);
jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put(MyJob.DATA, data);
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger(0, 0);
trigger.setName(jobName + "_Simpletrigger");
sched.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

И файл настроек `quartz.properties`:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
```

Но я не могу понять, какие `misfire` инструкции (`misfire instructions`) я должна установить для достижения этой цели. И какой `misfire` порог (`misfire threshold`)?
Буду благодарна также за любые ссылки на документацию/справочники на русском языке, касающиеся данной темы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Требуемое поведение было достигнуто после добавления в файл `quartz.properties` строки:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=1
```

и в код строки:

```
trigger.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
```